# Purview advanced resource sets pattern not matching

Tags: azure, azure-purview

I'm attempting to correctly group IoT ingested data in my Data Lake with Purview.

An example path is:

```
/100/101/IOT00002/2023/07/14/IOT00002-Received-2023-07-14T10:15:12.3310000Z-MID-568536ffd9c84797a4ca42d9b8b69802.json
```

Purview, by default, will create a resource set per folder with a device name in it. (IOT00002).

I've enabled Pattern Rules and loaded a match I believe will match (and applied it to the correct data source), on fresh rescan it doesn't apply the pattern.

What is wrong with my pattern when compared to the above path?

```
{mid:int}/{dt:int}/{folder:string}/{year:int}/{month:int}/{day:int}/{deviceid:string}-Received-{timestamp:timestamp}-MID-{messageid:guid}.json
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the timezone format.

```
2023-07-14T10:15:12.3310000Z
```

It need to be compatible with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/purview/how-to-resource-set-pattern-rules#syntax